# `TcpStream::connect` freezes `tokio` for one second

Tags: rust, async-await, tcp, rust-tokio

Consider the following snippet:

```
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tokio::time;

#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(async {
        loop {
            println!("[{:?}] I am alive!", Instant::now());
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        }
    });

    time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;

    let listener = TcpListener::bind((Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED, 0)).await.unwrap();
    let address = listener.local_addr().unwrap();

    drop(listener);

    time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;

    println!("Connecting");
    let _connection = TcpStream::connect(address).await;
    println!("Done");

    time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
}
```

In summary, on a single-threaded run of `tokio` I do the following:

- I spawn a task to print something every 100 ms, just know that everything keeps running.
- I bind a `TcpListener` anywhere, get its address.
- I `drop` the `TcpListener`.
- I then try to connect to the `TcpListener`'s former address.

Now, here is the output that I get:

```
[Instant { t: 322033533953690 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322033639639772 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322033740157897 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322033844392865 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322033948457992 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034051559169 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034155284597 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034257879982 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034361229691 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034462803458 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034564346433 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034668035678 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034772372462 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034877014330 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322034978911485 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322035080462270 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322035181321674 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322035282532413 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322035384651311 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322035488278141 }] I am alive!
Connecting
Done
[Instant { t: 322036543294463 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322036644255096 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322036747256653 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322036853860504 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322036955935656 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322037057575980 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322037162679980 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322037264386141 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322037365479256 }] I am alive!
[Instant { t: 322037468083176 }] I am alive!
```

As expected, the connection does not succeed. Somewhat reasonably, it takes around one second for the connection attempt to return (some timeout might have been put in place, I guess?).

HOWEVER, as you can notice by the lack of `I am alive` messages between `Connecting` and `Done`, the call to `TcpStream::connect` seems to be blocking...! The task I spawned to print every 100 ms does not execute (and nor does anything else) for the whole time the connection attempt is in progress.

I am baffled: `tokio` calls are supposed to be asynchronous, and not block the entire event loop.. right? Am I missing something here? Or did I stumble upon some sort of bug?

From my `Cargo.lock`:

```
...

[[package]]
name = "tokio"
version = "1.13.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "588b2d10a336da58d877567cd8fb8a14b463e2104910f8132cd054b4b96e29ee"

...
```

#### Update: About my system

- Operating System: MacOs Big Sur (11.1)
- Computer: MacBook Pro, Intel 64 bits
- Rust version: 1.56.0

#### Update: Additional observations

In the above code, changing `Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED` to `Ipv4Addr::LOCALHOST` significantly shortens the time to (fail to) establish the connection. It is still unclear to me whether or not it blocks while doing so.

Comment: Time the call to `connect` and see, pretty sure it'll return basically immediately and not block

Comment: Hello @MindSwipe, thanks for the comment. I did measure it and it does take one second. You can see it yourself from the log I attached, every line contains a nanosecond-accurate timestamp. For one second, the entire system freezes between `Connecting` and `Done`.

Comment: @MindSwipe That's a reasonable expectation, but the timestamps in the output seem to show otherrwise. The period between "I am alive" is 0.1s apart, except where the connection is established, where it's 1s.

Comment: @user4815162342 precisely :)

Comment: @MatteoMonti I can't reproduce this on Linux. `connect()` takes much shorter, but if I drastically reduce the time between timestamps, I am able to "interrupt" the `connect()` with the "I am alive" output. Perhaps tokio on Windows implements `connect()` in an async-unfriendly way, at least on the single-threaded runtime?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this on Windows, running OP's code on my machine results in about 0.1s between every `I am alive` print, even when the `Connecting` and `Done` happens it's 0.109s. [Image](https://imgur.com/a/cZDQaSe) (I modified OP's in so that the `Instant` gets created once before the loop and I print the `elapsed` every iteration of the loop, else it's the same). **Edit:** I just tested with OP's unaltered code and the delay was 0.107s

Comment: I'll add some information about my system in the main body of the question!

Comment: @MindSwipe The image indicates that resolving the invalid connection is faster for you than for the OP. Try reducing the sleeping interval in the watchdog task, and see if you can ever get it to print something between "Connecting" and "Done". If you manage to do so, then tokio works correctly. If that never happens, then you reproduced the OP's issue.

Comment: [Works for me](https://imgur.com/a/vXcnZ5m), seems like tokio is working properly for me

Comment: @MatteoMonti I think you should report this as an issue on the [tracker](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio). It looks like a bug in tokio.